# java simple http auth not working

Tags: java, rest, http-post, httpclient

I am looking to make an HTTP POST request and consume the resulting auth_token but the print statement in the while loop only prints `x-dnb-user=myusername&x-dnb-pwd=mypass`, as opposed to printing the response that it received from the server. I am unable to figure out where I have gone wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Also the response is given as a dictionary and the token is present in the 'Authorization' key in the dictionary how would I retrieve the token in that case?

```
public void sampleAuth(){
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication");
    try {
      ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x-dnb-user","myemail"));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x-dnb-pwd","mypass"));
      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably missing the Content-type

```
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Further, before you start rd.readLine the response, you should probably check the status code of the response.  The server may have flat out rejected you and there will be no lines to read!

```
int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if ( code == HttpStatus.SC_OK ) {
   // Now go fishing for the auth_token
   // Usually these things are returned as headers
} else {
   System.out.println( "You've been rejected, pal" );
}
```

I would need more details about the auth_token you are expecting, but my guess is that its in a header by the name of "auth_key" or something so you can just look it up.

Comment: hey Bob thanks for your response. I am indeed receiving a 400 code which is why I think there's nothing to read. The problem is the document says pass the userid and password in the HTTP header but all the documents instruct me to pass in the userid and password as NameValuPairs which is what I followed. Do you think that might be the problem? If so how would I pass the user_id and password in the header of a post request?

Comment: I don't know, but if the docs say a header give it a header.  Further, if they want actual Http Basic Auth, that is a spec all its own that has its own header and all:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication .  I would be surprised if HttpClient doesn't have some abstraction for this.